# Delete index column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

How to delete index column in pandas Dataframe? I do have '0,1,2,3' numbers columnwise and I want to delete it to plot the heatmap of my dataframe.

Comment: Can you show us what your DataFrame looks like by including the text from `df.head().to_dict()` in your question? also please include any code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

To write:

```
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

and to read from the CSV:

```
df.read_csv(filename, index_col=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, for the answer.

Comment: But I dont want to read the dataframe from CSV. I made a dataframe from my results and  in that Dataframe, I want to delete index column to make a heatmap from it.